# wrapping String in scala Future from java code

Tags: java, scala

I have the following method for testing:

```
public scala.concurrent.Future<String> send() { 
  return "OK"; //error - should wrap with future
}
```

How can I make it return a scala future (this is java code, so didn't find any example)?

Comment: Why are you returning a Java Future?  Those are two way different libraries. scala.concurrent.Future will be a wreck in Java as it will contain many aliases like $$anon$$. If you really need a different Future but don't want to use Scala, use Javaslang. Otherwise don't use Java or put java code in a class that your scala code will access to return a Future.

Comment: I am trying to write an interop utility, and this is only for testing

Comment: Open an IDE import Future and click implement methods. You need to implement each one. A sample:

Comment: new Future<String>(){ ... dozens of methods for you to write...}

Comment: Or call `Future.apply(...)` like you would in Scala?

Answer (score 2):

It's easy if you are working with the Scala 2.12.x library.

In Scala you would write [`Future(doSomeStuff())`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.12.1/scala/concurrent/Future$.html#apply[T](body:=%3ET)(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[T]). Or simply [`Future.successful("OK")`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.12.1/scala/concurrent/Future$.html#successful[T](result:T):scala.concurrent.Future[T]) if you really only want to wrap a literal in a `Future`.
In Java that translates to one of these:

```
import scala.concurrent.*;

public Future<String> send1() { 
    return Future.apply( () -> doSomeStuff(), ExecutionContext.global());
}

public Future<String> send2(ExecutionContext ec) { 
    return Future.apply( () -> doSomeStuff(), ec);
}

public Future<String> send3() { 
    return Future.successful("OK");
}
```

If you have more complex code to run than simply `"OK"` you'll have to use `send1` or `send2`. Which of those you want depends on whether you want to use the default [ExecutionContext](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.12.1/scala/concurrent/ExecutionContext.html) or let the caller decide.

---

If your Scala version is lower than 2.12.0, the `send1` method from above will look something like this:

```
import scala.concurrent.*;
import scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0;

public Future<String> send1() { 
    return Future$.MODULE$.apply( new AbstractFunction0<String>() {
        public String apply() {
            return doSomeStuff();
        }
    }, ExecutionContext$.MODULE$.global());
}
```